# Show $|x-1|$ and $|2x-1|$ are convex functions

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Show $|x-1|$ and $|2x-1|$ are convex functions using the fact that a convex function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies: for any $x^{(1)},x^{(2)}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \geq0$, where $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$ we have $f(\lambda_1x^{(1)}+\lambda_2x^{(2)})\leq\lambda_1f(x^{(1)})+\lambda_2f(x^{(2)})$

---

I figured out how to solve this for $|x|$ but I am having a hard time applying the same ideas to $|ax-b|$.

For $f(x)=|x|$ I did:

$\begin{align} f(\lambda_1x^{(1)}+\lambda_2x^{(2)}) &= |\lambda_1x^{(1)}+\lambda_2x^{(2)}| \\&\leq |\lambda_1x^{(1)}|+|\lambda_2x^{(2)}| \\&= \lambda_1|x^{(1)}|+\lambda_2|x^{(2)}| \\&= \lambda_1f(x^{(1)})+\lambda_2f(x^{(2)}) \end{align}$

Comment: Use that $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1$.

Comment: A V-shaped graph is pretty convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $f(x)=|x-1|$ and $g(x)=|2x-1|$.  Then for any $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb R$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\geq0$ with $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$, we have 
\begin{align*}
f(\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2)&=|\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2-1|\\
&=|\lambda_1x_1-\lambda_1+\lambda_2x_2-\lambda_2|\\
&\leq|\lambda_1x_1-\lambda_1|+|\lambda_2x_2-\lambda_2|\\
&=\lambda_1f(x_1)+\lambda_2f(x_2).
\end{align*}
So $f$ is convex, and the proof that $g$ is convex is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Composition of a convex function with an affine function is a convex function.
See also [Composition of convex function and affine function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654201/composition-of-convex-function-and-affine-function)