# Prove that $f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x} - \sum_{i=1}^{m} \log(b_i - \mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x})$ is convex

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis

> Let's consider $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$,
>
> $$f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x} - \sum_{i=1}^{m} \log(b_i - \mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x}), $$
>
> with $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $\mathbf{a}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, for $i = 1,\ldots,m$, so $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.
>
> - $\mathbf{dom}f$ contains the $\mathbf{x}$ for which the arguments of the logarithms are positive.
> - (Note: I have also seen $f$ written as, $f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{x} - \operatorname{sum}(\log(\mathbf{b} - \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}) )$.)
>
> I have to prove that $f$ is convex (most likely using the second derivative theorem).

I am not sure how to proceed. I have read that:

$$ \nabla \biggl( \sum_{i=1}^{m} \log(b_i - \mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x}) \biggr) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{1}{b_i - \mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{a}_i $$

But I don't fully understand it.

Comment: *Hint.* (1) $x \mapsto =-\log x$ is convex. (2) If $f$ is [affine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Representation) and $g$ is convex, then $g \circ f$ is also convex. (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/654201/9340), for instance.)

Comment: Ok that is a way but I have to use the second derivative theorem ($\nabla^2 f(x) \succcurlyeq 0$) based on the hints I have. I am on confused on how I can calculate the gradient and the hessian of $f$.

Comment: @DontWorry Your comment suggests that you might not be familiar with matrix calculus. I've therefore written an answer with detailed calculations of the entries of the Hessian of $f$. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $j, k \in \{1, \ldots,n \}$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}\left(\mathbf c^\mathsf T \mathbf x\right) 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left(\mathbf c^\mathsf T \mathbf x\right)\right) 
= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(c_k\right) 
= 0
$$
and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}\left(- \sum_{i=1}^{m} \ln\left(b_i - \mathbf a_i^\mathsf T\mathbf{x}\right)\right)
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left(- \sum_{i=1}^{m} \ln\left(b_i - \mathbf a_i^\mathsf T\mathbf{x}\right)\right)\right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{b_i - \mathbf a_i^\mathsf T\mathbf{x}}\cdot \left(\mathbf a_i\right)_k\right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{\left(b_i - \mathbf a_i^\mathsf T\mathbf{x}\right)^2}\cdot \left(\mathbf a_i\right)_k \cdot \left(\mathbf a_i\right)_j.
\end{align}

Therefore, the Hessian matrix of $f$ in $\mathbf x$ is given by
$$
\mathbf H_f(\mathbf x) = \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{\left(b_i - \mathbf a_i^\mathsf T \mathbf x\right)^2} \mathbf a_i \mathbf a_i^\mathsf T.
$$
Finally, $\mathbf H_f$ is positive semi-definite since
$$
\mathbf v^\mathsf T \left[\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{\left(b_i - \mathbf a_i^\mathsf T \mathbf x\right)^2} \mathbf a_i \mathbf a_i^\mathsf T \right] \mathbf v = 
\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{\left(b_i - \mathbf a_i^\mathsf T \mathbf x\right)^2} \mathbf v^\mathsf T\mathbf a_i \mathbf a_i^\mathsf T \mathbf v = \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{\left(\mathbf v^\mathsf T\mathbf a_i\right)^2}{\left(b_i - \mathbf a_i^\mathsf T \mathbf x\right)^2} \geq 0
$$
for all $\mathbf v, \mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n.$

Comment: Would it be possible to write the calculations with even more details or how short explanation? For example in $\sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{1}{b_i - \mathbf{a}_i^T\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{a}_i$, how $\mathbf{a}_i^T$ appears on numerator as $\mathbf{a}_i$ without transpose? Also because $\mathbf{a}_i^T \mathbf{x}$ i would expect $a_{i1}x_1 + a_{i2}x_2+ \dot + a_{in}x_n$ so only one term would remain with each partial derivative  but we end up with the whole vector $\mathbf{a_i}$.

Comment: @DontWorry In standard Euclidean space, the gradient of $\mathbf x\mapsto- \sum_{i=1}^{m}\ln\left(b_i-\mathbf a_i^\mathsf T\mathbf{x}\right)$ is the (column) vector whose $k$-th entry is given by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left(-\sum_{i=1}^{m} \ln\left(b_i-\mathbf a_i^\mathsf T\mathbf{x}\right)\right).$ And we have$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left(- \sum_{i=1}^{m} \ln\left(b_i-\mathbf a_i^\mathsf T\mathbf{x}\right)\right)=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{b_i-\mathbf a_i^\mathsf T\mathbf{x}}\cdot\left(\mathbf a_i\right)_k,$ where $\left(\mathbf a_i\right)_k$ denotes the $k$-th entry of $\mathbf a_i$.

Comment: why after the first differentiation we get $\mathbf{a_i}$ while after the second differentiation we get $\mathbf{a_i^T}$, is it based on the fact that $\mathbf{H_f}$ has to be a $n \times n$ matrix, so we manipulate the dimensions of $\mathbf{a_i}$ in such a way to get what we want?

Comment: @DontWorry Have you had a look at the definition of a Hessian matrix? The Hessian matrix of $f$ evaluated at $\mathbf x$ is the $n \times n$ matrix whose $(j,k)$ entry is given by $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}(\mathbf x)$. And the $(j,k)$ entry of $\mathbf a_i \mathbf a_i^\mathsf T$ equals $(\mathbf a_i)_j \cdot (\mathbf a_i)_k$.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, the easiest way to prove this is to realize that $f$ is a sum of convex functions.  However, since you are interested in proving this by differentiation, I wanted to present a coordinate-free calculation to complement the answer obtained previously.

First, notice that

$$ df = \mathbf{c}^\intercal d\mathbf{x} - \sum_{i} \frac{-\mathbf{a}_i^\intercal d\mathbf{x}}{b_i-\mathbf{a}_i^\intercal\mathbf{x}} = \left(\mathbf{c}+\sum_i\frac{\mathbf{a}_i}{b_i-\mathbf{a}_i^\intercal\mathbf{x}}\right)\cdot d\mathbf{x} = \nabla f\cdot d\mathbf{x}, $$
Which shows that $\nabla f$ is the term in parentheses.  To compute the second derivative $\nabla^2 f$, it suffices to notice that

$$ d\nabla f = \sum_i \frac{\mathbf{a}_i\left(\mathbf{a}_i^\intercal d\mathbf{x}\right)}{\left(b_i - \mathbf{a}_i^\intercal\mathbf{x}\right)^2} = \left(\sum_i \frac{\mathbf{a}_i\mathbf{a}_i^\intercal}{\left(b_i-\mathbf{a}_i^\intercal\mathbf{x}\right)^2} \right)d\mathbf{x} = \left(\nabla^2f\right)d\mathbf{x}, $$
Which agrees with what was presented earlier. From this it follows immediately that $\mathbf{v}^\intercal\left(\nabla^2f\right)\mathbf{v}\geq 0$ for any $\mathbf{v}$ since both the numerator and denominator are sums of quadratic terms.